# Just now I know he is stingy

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, time, adverbial-phrases

Your friend telling that guy is stingy and now you know it.

> *I **just** know that he is stingy.*
>
> ***Just now*** I know he is stingy.

Can we put the "just now" in the front?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I just know* has nothing to do with time.  In that expression, *just* means "for reasons that cannot be stated".  An example of that usage would be

> You're hiding something from me — I just know it!

… meaning that I have a very strong guess, maybe from reading your facial expression.  (It's just an expression — technically, I don't really know for sure!)

---

You could say *Now I know…*.  That implies that you recently discovered some evidence that made you form that opinion.

> I saw how small a tip he left for the waiter.  **Now I know he is stingy.**

---

*Just now I know…* feels wrong.  *Just now* is not as open-ended as *now*.  *Just now* means "at this moment" (a very brief instant in the present) or "a little time ago" (in the past).  On the other hand, once you know something, you continue to know it.  Knowledge is not something that ends in an instant, whether in the present or in the recent past.  You could say instead:

> **Just now I learned that he is stingy.**

or

> **Just now I realized how stingy he really is.**

The difference is that *learned* and *realized* are completable actions.

Answer (score 3):

> "I just learned that he is stingy."

That's how I'd say it. The verb *learn* refers to a more precise moment in time than *know*, so *just learned* sounds more natural than *just know*.

There's no need to put the "now" with just in that sentence, because the phrase "just learned" means that this learning happened in the immediate past.

However, you could say:

> "Just now, I learned that he is stingy."

The two-word phrase *just now* gets its [own entry in some dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=just%20now&ls=a). NOAD defines it as:

> **just now**
>   1 at this moment
>   2 a little time ago

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

> I just found out that he is stingy.

"Just now" isn't really used, because "just" is sufficient by itself in most cases to indicate that something has happened very recently... except in the first case you posted (*I just know that he is stingy*), "just" has a different meaning: it means *I know only that he is stingy*.

More examples:

> You just went to the bathroom, why do you need to go again already?
>
> Hurray — we just won the lottery!
>
> Derek just got over a bad cold, so he is not ready to go ice climbing.

Even in other senses, "just now" isn't necessary; "just" is sufficient and more natural-sounding:

> I am just now realizing he is stingy.
>
> I am just realizing he is stingy.

Comment: *just now* is used, just not as in your example. But you could say "Just now I *found out* he is stingy". *just now* indicates a time change up to now, while *know* is a static state.

Comment: *Just now I found out he is stingy* is grammatically OK but it is not a natural-sounding English sentence. The only reason I can give is that the phrase *I just found out* is much more common.

Comment: How about "*Just now* I realized he is stingy"? Keep in mind that "just now", being the realization that just occurred, is being emphasized.

Comment: "Just" + _present tense_ is quite different from "Just" + _past tense_.

Comment: I still maintain you could convert "Just now I realized he is stingy" to "I just realized he is stingy" with no change in meaning, and it would sound more natural.